# How to mock the environment variables to write unit tests for a grails application?

Tags: grails, groovy, junit

I have the following controller in which a method returns keywords based on the environment it is running on.

```
import grails.util.Environment

class SearchController {

    static String currentEnvironment() {
        def curEnvironment
        if (Environment.current == Environment.PRODUCTION){
            curEnvironment = 'prod'
        }
        else {
            curEnvironment = 'alpha'
        }
        return curEnvironment
    }
}
```

How do I write a unit testing to mock the environment variables? Something like:

```
void testEnvironment(){
    //mock(grails.util.Environment.current = "PRODUCTION")
    assert controller.currentEnvironment == 'prod'
}
```

I tried running the test with `-Dgrails.env=prod` and it works, but this approach is not generic. So I was wondering if I could set the environment variables for the tests or better mock it.

Comment: What kind of mocking framework do you use? With Spock these two lines would do it: `GroovyMock(Environment, global: true); Environment.current >> Environment.PRODUCTION`

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but as an FYI, there really is no good reason to have a static method defined in a controller which returns a value to indicate which environment the app is running in.